# Can someone receive my calls on viber even I deleted the application, I called by mistake

Tags: notifications, calls, viber-messenger

Had called someone on viber by mistake, how can I let him not receiving the calls notification, I already blocked him; should I delete theapplication? Tour assistance is needed please

Comment: i am not sure what you asking. you need to unregister before deleting

Comment: from my understanding you already called, so the call notification is already happen?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel

Answer (score 0):

If you already called the person there is no way to delete the notification.